# How to insert a variable in xpath within a for loop?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, xpath

```
for i in range(length):
        # print(i)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
        range = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class = 'button'])[i]").click()


        content2 = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content2,"html.parser")
        name2 = soup2.find('h1', {'data-qa-target': 'ProviderDisplayName'}).text
        phone2 = soup2.find('a', {'class': 'click-to-call-button-secondary hg-track mobile-click-to-call'}).text
        print(name2, phone2)
```

Hey guy I am trying to scrape the First and last Name, Telephone for each person this website: https://www.healthgrades.com/family-marriage-counseling-directory. I want the (l.4) button to adapt to the variable (i). if i manually change i to a number everything works perfectly fine. But as soon as I placed in the variable i it doesn't work, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
range = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class = 'button'])[i]").click()
```

do this :

```
range = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[@class = 'button'])[{i}]").click()
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.healthgrades.com/family-marriage-counseling-directory")

for name in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"):
  print(name.text)
```

**Output :**

```
Noe Gutierrez, MSW
Melissa Huston, LCSW
Gina Kane, LMHC
Dr. Mary Marino, PHD
Emili-Erin Puente, MED
Richard Vogel, LMFT
Lynn Bednarz, LCPC
Nicole Palow, LMHC
Dennis Hart, LPCC
Dr. Robert Meeks, PHD
Jody Davis
Dr. Kim Logan, PHD
Artemis Paschalis, LMHC
Mark Webb, LMFT
Deirdre Holland, LCSW-R
John Paul Dilorenzo, LMHC
Joseph Hayes, LPC
Dr. Maylin Batista, PHD
Ella Gray, LCPC
Cynthia Mack-Ernsdorff, MA
Dr. Edward Muldrow, PHD
Rachel Sievers, LMFT
Dr. Lisa Burton, PHD
Ami Owen, LMFT
Sharon Lorber, LCSW
Heather Rowley, LCMHC
Dr. Bonnie Bryant, PHD
Marilyn Pearlman, LCSW
Charles Washam, BCD
Dr. Liliana Wolf, PHD
Christy Kobe, LCSW
Dana Paine, LPCC
Scott Kohner, LCSW
Elizabeth Krzewski, LMHC
Luisa Contreras, LMFT
Dr. Joel Nunez, PHD
Susanne Sacco, LISW
Lauren Reminger, MA
Thomas Recher, AUD
Kristi Smith, LCSW
Kecia West, LPC
Gregory Douglas, MED
Gina Smith, LCPC
Anne Causey, LPC
Dr. David Greenfield, PHD
Olga Rothschild, LMHC
Dr. Susan Levin, PHD
Ferguson Jennifer, LMHC
Marci Ober, LMFT
Christopher Checke, LMHC

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Update 2 :**

```
leng = len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))
for i in range(leng):
  driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[text()='View Profile'])[{i}]").click()
```

Comment: hey thank you for your answer but sadly this error code occurs then : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'range' referenced before assignment

Comment: Check out the updated code 1, it works in my local

Comment: `range` is used in `for i in range(length):`

Comment: Hey thank you for the replies, the problem is that I have to press the button (View Profile) so I can access the phone number not only the first and last name.

Comment: No you did not mention that in your post itself. also what is length in your code ?

Comment: the length is 60 (how many names there are on the site) @cruisepandey

Comment: for me it comes as 50, not 60 @AdrianReichert

Comment: weird, because I think I counted the people on the website and it was 60. But to scrape the phone number I have to press on (View Profile). I made this work and i can also go back, the only thing I need help is how I can choose the next (View Profile) Button of the different person. @cruisepandey

Comment: You can print this `print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']")))` to get number of name in that page

Comment: also you can loop this xpath, `(//a[text()='View Profile'])[1]` in a loop 1 represent the first view profile button, similarly 2 would represent 2nd button and so on... see the update 2 above.